# Backbone.js Get a PDF response

Tags: html, pdf, backbone.js, backbone-views

When I do a get request from the server I get a bytearray response of a pdf.

[image]

How do I display it on my webpage with backbone.js?

So far I’ve been working with backbone.js and rendered JSON data without problems, but now I am stuck.

**Clarification:**

I need to create a backbone view that displays the PDF that I get through the GET request.

Comment: You probably need to send a `Content-type: application/pdf` header, but I don't know how to do that in backbone

Comment: Displaying a PDF in a web page is not a trivial thing to do. Are you using some library for it, or do you meaan that you want the browser to allow the user to download the PDF?

Comment: When i do a GET request with backbone.js, I get a pdf as a response from the server. I can't get the response to be an object.

Comment: Try Google docs [viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer). May be it will work. You can embed the viewer in a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your GET request is via an AJAX request which returns the data in the form of a string (not byte array). Converting a string into a PDF isn't possible.

Alternative solution. I would stream and cache or temporarily save the PDF somewhere in the server then your HTTP response would be the path to the PDF location. You can add a token, expiration or delete the temp PDF after x amount of time.

You can then use Backbone to render the PDF using the 
    `<embed src="/some.pdf" />`